# Serve a dynamically generated image with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, image

How do I serve a dynamically generated image in Django?

I have an html tag

```
<html>
...
    <img src="images/dynamic_chart.png" />
...
</html>
```

linked up to this request handler, which creates an in-memory image

```
def chart(request):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (300,300), "#FFFFFF")
    data = [(i,randint(100,200)) for i in range(0,300,10)]
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.polygon(data, fill="#000000")
    # now what?
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

I also plan to change the requests to AJAX, and add some sort of caching mechanism, but my understanding is that wouldn't affect this part of the solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume you're using PIL (Python Imaging Library). You need to replace your last line with (for example, if you want to serve a PNG image):

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
img.save(response, "PNG")
return response
```

See [here](http://effbot.org/zone/django-pil.htm) for more information.

Comment: I'm using PIL for this example but probably going to use other libraries like matplotlib. Should work too though.

Comment: use content_type instead of mime type if you are using Django 1.10 +

Comment: Update for python3 

from PILLOW import Image
from io import BytesIO

img = Image.open("some_image.jpg")
img_byte_arr = BytesIO()
img.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')

return HttpResponse(
 img_byte_arr.getvalue(), 
 "image/png"
)

Answer (score 3):

I'm relatively new to Django myself. I haven't been able to find anything in Django itself, but I have stumbled upon a project on Google Code that may be of some help to you:

[django-dynamic-media-serve](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-media-serve/)

Comment: Good link, might be useful when I get to the caching stage

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution of the same problem

And for me this simple approach worked fine:

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def dyn_view(request):

    response = FileResponse(open("image.png","rb"))
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use BytesIO. BytesIO is like a buffer. So one can save the image (which is fast enough than writing to disk) in that buffer.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import io

def chart(request):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (240, 240), color=(250,160,170))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((20, 40), 'some_text')

    buff = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(buff, 'jpeg')
    return HttpResponse(buff.getvalue(), content_type='image/jpeg')
```