# Python + Cairo: How Do I Save a Drawing?

Tags: python, cairo

Suppose I create a blank area in a window and draw some lines in it, how can I save that in a .png or .jpg? Or maybe convert it to an object PIL could understand?

Answer (score 6):

Answer here: [Using Pycairo to generate images dynamically and serve in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004854/using-pycairo-to-generate-images-dynamically-and-serve-in-django) though it only says how to save to .png.

```
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 100, 100)
context = cairo.Context(surface)
# Draw something ...

surface.write_to_png('filename')
```

Comment: From information in the original question your link refers to, it sounds like you could use a `surface.get_data()` call coupled with a PIL `Image.frombuffer()` call to create a PIL image which could then be saved in other formats, such as jpg.